# Question about C syntax

Tags: c

I have a friend who was working on a c example from a book and he did a code like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

int main()
{
    float numGrade;

    printf("\n\nPlease enter your numerical grade: ");
    scanf("%f", &numGrade);

    if (numGrade >= 90)
        printf("\nYou got an A.\n\n");
    else if (90 > numGrade >= 80)
        printf("\nYou got a B.\n\n");
    else if (80 > numGrade >= 70)
        printf("\nYou got a C.\n\n");
    else if (70 > numGrade >= 60)
        printf("\nYou got a D.\n\n");
    else if (60 > numGrade)
        printf("\nYou got an F.\n\n");
    else
        printf("\nThis is an invalid grade!\n");
}
```

Is there any problem with doing it like that or should he do it like :

```
int main()
{
    float numGrade;

    printf("\n\nPlease enter your numerical grade: ");
    scanf("%f", &numGrade);

    if (numGrade >= 90)
        printf("\nYou got an A.\n\n");
    else if (90 > numGrade && numGrade >= 80)
        printf("\nYou got a B.\n\n");
    else if (80 > numGrade && numGrade >= 70)
        printf("\nYou got a C.\n\n");
    else if (70 > numGrade && numGrade >= 60)
        printf("\nYou got a D.\n\n");
    else if (60 > numGrade)
        printf("\nYou got an F.\n\n");
    else
        printf("\nThis is an invalid grade!\n");
}
```

Comment: When you compiled and ran it, did it work the way you expected it to? (Hint: it won't.)

Comment: Are you asking if it is ok to remove the `#include` ?

Comment: @Marlon: It is hard to notice, but the question is apparently about `90 > numGrade >= 80` conditions in the first example. Includes are assumed in the second example.

Comment: Next time please format your code, it takes 30 seconds and people are more willing to help.

Comment: Also note that logically you don't need both comparisons. Imagine for example comparing < 80 then < 90; if the second comparison is true then the value is >= 80 and < 90.

Comment: The `#pragma` is worrying - what warning/error is it suppressing?  The `#include <math.h>` is superfluous.

Comment: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcz0bys%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - Function was declared depreciated.

Comment: The pragma warning is still taught in the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first example won't work at all.

The first comparison in each test will return either 0 or 1. So it will always fail the second.

EDIT:

<strike>However, the program will probably still "work" the way it is desired, simply because the second comparison in each test is not needed.</strike>

Comment: That is what I was wondering. It actually worked correctly for a lot of numbers entered except 66 it went wrong. He changed it but I wanted to verify that it was wrong

Comment: I haven't run it yet, but I don't think that first example will ever give a grade besides A, F, or invalid?

Comment: In case it's not clear, comparison operators don't chain in the way you might think.  `x < y < z` doesn't mean `x < y && y < z`; it means `(x < y) < z`, where `(x < y)` yields either 0 or 1.  The fact that you need to write the `&&` explicitly isn't so bad.  The tricky part is that `x < y < z` is perfectly valid code -- it just means something very different from what it typically means in mathematical notation.